Adding cicerone guide to shiny module
I am having trouble adding a cicerone guide to my shiny app module (golem framework). I am using cicerone package version 1.0.5.9000.
I have tried adding the cicerone calls in the module ui and module server as follows:
mod_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    cicerone::use_cicerone(),
    bslib::card(
      bslib::layout_sidebar(
        sidebar = bslib::sidebar(
          width=450,
          shiny::selectInput(ns("name"), "Select Name", choices = c("Sam","Allie","Ted"), selected = "Sam"),
          shiny::selectInput(ns("activity"), "Select Activity", choices = c("Soccer","Tennis","Basketball"), selected = "Soccer", multiple=TRUE)
          shiny::actionButton(ns("help"),"Help")
          )
       )
    )
}

mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    guide <- cicerone::Cicerone$
  new()$
  step(
    el = "name",
    title = "Step 1",
    description = "This is step 1.",
    position = "bottom-center"
  )$
  step(
    el = "activity",
    title = "Step 2",
    description = "This is step 2.",
  )

  shiny::observeEvent(input$help,{
      guide$init()$start()
  })
 }
)}

When I do this, I don't get any errors, but the help button does not trigger the guide to start as expected.

Please provide us with a reproducible example. Cheers
